# Aligning articles of section to display with third element centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get the articles of my section to display exactly like this (with the third article centered when expanded to a fuller browser width): https://www.screencast.com/t/vGdpZ91l

I've explored all the display options of CSS. The current CSS is set to `display: inline-flex;`

Here is my CSS/HTML. Help would be much appreciated.

```css
.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.places article {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="7-places.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <section class="places">
        <h1>Places</h1>
        <article class="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        </article>
        <article class="apartment">
        <h2>Apartment</h2>
        </article>
        <article class="dorm">
        <h2>Dorm</h2>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex on the parent, and set it to `flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;`.

```css
.places {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.places h1 {
  align-content: top-left;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.places article {
  width: 390px;
  border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.places article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="places">
    <h1>Places</h1>
    <article class="home">
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="apartment">
      <h2>Apartment</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="dorm">
      <h2>Dorm</h2>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @jimmytt awesome! np :)

Comment: @jimmytt btw if you move the `h1` out of `.places` then you don't need to specify `width: 100%` on the `h1` but I didn't want to change your markup since what you have currently will work.

Comment: Wonderful tip @Michael Coker. I am digging Stack Overflow!